# Cast to decima in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having the input data in text format like below. I need to convert this into Decimal in spark Scala. Please help me the cast(DecimalType) statement.

+0000025.42

I have tried .cast(DecimalType(11,2)) and it is displaying Null

Comment: what is plus symbol in your input ??

Answer (score 0):

Might be having some `text` characters in that column because of that It is not able to convert data to `decimal(11,2)` type & It is adding `null` in that column.

Check data in that column.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("+0000025.42"),("sample")).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+-----------+
|value      |
+-----------+
|+0000025.42|
|sample     |
+-----------+


scala> df.select($"value".cast("decimal(11,2)").as("value")).show(false)
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|25.42|
|null |
+-----+
```